# linksys e1000 and wrt120n setting up a wireless access point or repeater

Tags: networking, wireless-networking

I have a linksys e1000 as my primary router in my house, however my house appears to be to large to pull good signal from across the house and up the stairs. So I need to setup some time of access point.

I have an old router, a linksys wrt120n that Im not using at the moment. So I am hoping I can come up with a means of keeping my current router as the primary and extend my network through this other router somewhere between the router and the dead spots of the house.

Problem is I can't find to many articles on this anywhere as there are way to many possibilities apparently.

So I am hoping someone with better home networking experience then I have can help me figure this out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would highly recommend checking out [DD-WRT](http://www.dd-wrt.com/site/index) to accomplish this if your routers do not support acting as repeaters.  The Linksys e1000 is a supported router that can be loaded with DD-WRT according to the supported [database](http://www.dd-wrt.com/site/support/router-database).  There are a lot of good articles and walkthroughs on the DD-WRT website that are linked from the downloads under the wikis on Additional Information.

I've been buying old WRT54G routers for years and converting them to repeaters for myself and others and DD-WRT is solid.  **Please make sure to read the instructions carefully and check your router version before flashing any firmware**

Comment: No problem.  The Wiki articles there are well written, just make sure to read through them fully before performing the update.  I bricked one and was lucky enough to recover it through a very long process.  I've actually run DD-WRT on some non-repeaters because it offers more functionality than the factory firmware in most cases.